# Spring Batch: How to inject StepContribution into ItemStreamReader bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-batch

I want to inject `StepContribution` bean into my custom `ItemStreamReader` which I injected into step in XML configuration:

```
<step id="myStep">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk reader="myReader" writer="myWriter"
               commit-interval="${app.batch.size}"/>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

Is it possible to do that? Here is what I need to get:

```
class MyReader implements ItemStreamReader<MyDtoObject> {
    @Resource
    private StepContribution contribution;

    public MyDtoObject read() {
        // do something with contribution for this step
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not possible. Why do you need that? Maybe is it possible to reach the same goal in a different way